# How to give color for Annotation in google line Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});
data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');

data.addRow(["A", null, null, 1, 1, 0.5]);
data.addRow(["B", null, null, 2, 0.5, 1]);
data.addRow(["C", null, null, 4, 1, 0.5]);
data.addRow(["D", null, null, 8, 0.5, 1]);
data.addRow(["E", null, null, 7, 1, 0.5]);
data.addRow(["F", null, null, 7, 0.5, 1]);
data.addRow(["G", 'Foo', 'Foo annotation', 8, 1, 0.5]);
data.addRow(["H", null, null, 4, 0.5, 1]);
data.addRow(["I", null, null, 2, 1, 0.5]);
data.addRow(["J", null, null, 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
data.addRow(["K", 'Bar', 'Bar annotation', 3, 1, 0.5]);
data.addRow(["L", null, null, 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
data.addRow(["M", null, null, 1, 1, 0.5]);
data.addRow(["N", null, null, 1, 0.5, 1]);

// Create and draw the visualization.
new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
draw(data, {
    curveType: 'function',
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
        maxValue: 10
    },
    annotations: {
        style: 'line',color:'#ff0000'
    }
 });
}
```

I wnat to give color to Annotation 
In the Above code Color property is not apply to the the annotation 
Please someone help me out where i make mistake

Answer (score 0):

to change the color of the *line*, try option for --> `annotations.stem.color`

to change the color of the *text*, use --> `annotations.textStyle.color`

```
    annotations: {
      style: 'line',
      stem: {
        color: '#ff0000'
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: '#ff0000'
      }
    }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawVisualization();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawVisualization, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');

  data.addRow(["A", null, null, 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["B", null, null, 2, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["C", null, null, 4, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["D", null, null, 8, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["E", null, null, 7, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["F", null, null, 7, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["G", 'Foo', 'Foo annotation', 8, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["H", null, null, 4, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["I", null, null, 2, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["J", null, null, 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["K", 'Bar', 'Bar annotation', 3, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["L", null, null, 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
  data.addRow(["M", null, null, 1, 1, 0.5]);
  data.addRow(["N", null, null, 1, 0.5, 1]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data, {
    curveType: 'function',
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      maxValue: 10
    },
    annotations: {
      style: 'line',
      stem: {
        color: '#ff0000'
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: '#ff0000'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

---

**note:**

recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, instead of `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will *only* change the `load` statement

`google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});`

you can also include the `callback` in the `load` statement, as in the above snippet...